# What should the Context be for Intent(Context, Class) in a dialog box?

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-context

I have a dialog box, which I am using to switch between activities (when an error is thrown, sort of). I am used to using `Intent(this, class)` to switch between activities, but in a `DialogBox` what should the context be instead of "`this`".

My code:

```
package com.example.partyorganiser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Attendance_Dialog extends DialogFragment {
    Context context;
     public Attendance_Dialog(Context c){
         this.context = c;
     }
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState, final Context context) {
            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("NEED TO CREATE A PARTY FIRST: MENU OR ADD A PARTY")
                   .setPositiveButton("MENU", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                          Intent switch_menu = new Intent(context, MenuList.class);
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("ADD A PARTY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           Intent switch_addparty = new Intent(context , AddParty.class);
                           startActivity(switch_addparty);
                       }
                   });
            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            return builder.create();
        }
}
```

Comment: youractivityName.this

Comment: get the error "no enclosing instance of the type (my class) is accessible in scope.

Comment: Normal activity, it will add nothing to the question if I add it, I would think??? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the context to the Dialog.

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog{
    Context context;
    //Constructor
    public MyDialog(Context c){
        this.context = c;
    }

    //Example of using the context
    public void doSomethingWithContext(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
    }
} 

//Creating MyDialog and giving it a context
MyDialog md = new MyDialog(this);
md.show();
```

In a fragment you can use `getActivity()` to get the context from activity where you started the fragment from.